# Gatsby Source Drupal not fetching data when trying to deploy to netlify/heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, graphql, gatsby

I have a site running Gatsby and Gatsby-Source-Drupal7, it is a plugin that uses Graphql to make an axios get request to https://stagingsupply.htm-mbs.com/restws_resource.json and uses the json data to query. I am able to run it just fine on my computer by going to localhost:8000 and it creates over 200k nodes, but when I try to deploy on any cloud service provider like Gatsby Cloud or Netlify it doesn't fetch any nodes or data at all from the site.

### Warning from console

```
Starting to fetch data from Drupal
warn The gatsby-source-drupal7 plugin has generated no Gatsby nodes. Do you need
 it?
```

### Code

code from gatsby config

```
module.exports = {
    siteMetadata: {
      title: `new`,
        siteUrl: `https://www.yourdomain.tld`,
    },
    plugins: [
      {
        resolve: `gatsby-source-drupal7`,
        options: {
          baseUrl: `https://stagingsupply.htm-mbs.com/`,
          apiBase: `restws_resource.json`, // optional, defaults to `restws_resource.json`
        },
      },
    ]
}
```

gatsby-config.js from node_modules/gatsby-source-drupal7

```
const createNode = actions.createNode; // Default apiBase to `jsonapi`

    apiBase = apiBase || `restws_resource.json`; // Fetch articles.
    // console.time(`fetch Drupal data`)

    console.log(`Starting to fetch data from Drupal`);
    const data = yield axios.get(`${baseUrl}/${apiBase}`, {
      auth: basicAuth
    });
    const allData = yield Promise.all(_.map(data.data.list,
```

Link to repo that works on local computer https://github.com/nicholastorr/gatsby-d7

any and all help will be appreciated

Comment: Does it also build correctly locally? (`localhost:9000`)

Comment: yes builds perfectly generates 200k nodes

Comment: What version of Node are you running locally?

Comment: node v14.17.1 npm 6.14.13 Gatsby CLI version: 4.6.0 Gatsby version: 4.6.0, I also added those specific node versions to my NODE_ENV variables and engines in package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was nothing Gatsby or Node related, my site was block the IP of the server :>

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, you've played around with the Node versions using `NODE_ENV` and `engines` workarounds. My guess also relies on a mismatching Node version between environments but as [Netlify docs](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/manage-dependencies/) suggests, there are only two ways of customizing Node versions to manage dependencies.

> - Set a `NODE_VERSION` environment variable.
> - Add a `.node-version` or `.nvmrc` file to the site’s base directory in your repository. This will also tell any other developer using the
>   repository which version of Node.js it depends on.

Without seeing your Netlify build command (to see the `NODE_VERSION`) there's no `.node-version` nor `.nvmrc` in your repository. I'd try creating it at the root of the project with the `v14.17.1` in it and trying a fresh install.

In addition, double-check other server-related conflicts like IP-blocking, etc.

Comment: 4:27:37 PM: Downloading and installing node v14.17.1...
4:27:37 PM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v14.17.1/node-v14.17.1-linux-x64.tar.xz...
4:27:38 PM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
4:27:38 PM: Checksums matched!
4:27:41 PM: Now using node v14.17.1 (npm v6.14.13)
4:27:43 PM: Using PHP version 8.0
4:27:43 PM: Started restoring cached node modules
4:27:43 PM: Finished restoring cached node modules
4:27:43 PM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.14.13

Comment: It is installing the same node and npm versions as my local computer but still same error